# Como funciona el ciclo For en los arrays?

Tags: java, array

Estoy practicando ejercicios con arrays, encontre este
codigo:

```
int[] n = {1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1};
int[] occ = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    ++occ[n[i]];
}
System.out.println(occ[1]);
System.out.println(occ[4]);
```

el resultado de correr el codigo es 3 y 2
pero no entiendo esta parte que funcion realiza 
 `++occ[n[i]];`

Comment: Pues lo que yo veo al correr el codigo en modo debug es que el `++` le da un aumento en` 1` a `occ` , despues hay como una asigancion en esta parte `[n[i]]` pero no he entendido mas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Analicemos el código un poco:

```
int[] n = {1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1};
```

declara e inicializa un array de 10 posiciones que guarda 10 números enteros (`int`) definidos. Nótese que **todos los números están entre 0 y 6**

```
int[] occ = new int[6];
```

declara e inicializa un array de 6 posiciones, pero no se definen los valores. Como un int no puede ser `null`, todas las posiciones toman el valor por defecto: 0 (cero)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) { //bucle de 10 iteraciones
    ++occ[n[i]];
}
```

La parte compleja del bucle la voy a reescribir así:

```
int indice= n[i]; //tomamos el valor de la posición i del array n
++(occ[indice]); //equivalente a occ[indice] = occ[indice] +1;
```

Por tanto, n es un array que guarda las posiciones que se van a ver incrementadas en 1 del array occ.

Por ejemplo, en el array n aparece el 1 tres veces, por lo que la posición 1 del array occ será incrementada 3 veces. El 4 aparece 2 veces, por lo que esa posición valdrá 2 tras el bucle.

```
System.out.println(occ[1]); // 3
System.out.println(occ[4]); // 2
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento paso a paso [aquí](https://ideone.com/7z5Vce)